# Cannot connect facebook using another account

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am using the latest Android SDK of Facebook.

I have an application which connects to facebook using LoginButton. If I try to log in to my account (which is the owner of Facebook Application) it is OK.

However, if I try to log in to another account, there is shown a dialog which asks for permission after clicking 'OK' nothing happens. I cannot connect to that facebook account and fetch user data.

**Note:** I should also mention that the same scenario occurs if I try to log in to that account using the sample applications in the Facebook SDK.

Could anyone help me solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:** I tried to make the other account owner of my application and it works. I can log in now. But I am still curious about this issue.

**Update 2:** I solved my problem. Check my answer below

Comment: Are you getting any error while logging in ?

Comment: What did you do to try "log in to another account"?
I thought you only can log in to the same account of the facebook app in your phone.

Comment: @uDevel I mean, I try to log in an account which is different than the owner of the application.

Comment: I make that account Owner in Application Settings, and now I can log in to that account.

Comment: Seems it is the problem of hash key mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It is because my Facebook app is not available for public.

Solution:

**1)** Go to Facebook Developer Console.

**2)** Select the app.

**3)** Click Status & Reviews tab.

**4)** Switch 'the availability of your app to public' on. It is the big switch up there.

**PS:** If you cannot switch it on, then try to add a contact email at: **Settings** > **Basic** > **Contact Email**

Answer (score 0):

Get the Key hashes from your project by putting this code in MainActivity after OnCreate

```
 try {

           PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

           for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
           {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
           }

          } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
           Log.e("name not found", e.toString());
          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
           Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
          }
```

Go to logcat and copy the Key hashes from there
Then go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and click on your app you created then go to settings paste your key in Key Hashes box and click save changes.
Make sure that you app is public and available to all users if not public then go to settings put your email in Contact Email box and click save changes then check the small circle next to app name.

Comment: I double checked the key, key is the same which is in the developer's page

Comment: Then make another facebook app and get new app_id and put it in your android application may this work